# OLEDB Transactions

Tags: oledb, atl

I am trying to use transactions to speed up the insertion of a large number of database entries.

I am using SQL Server Compact 4.0 and the ATL OLEDB API based on C++.

Here is the basic sequence:

```
sessionobj.StartTransaction();
tableobject.Insert(//);
tableobject.Insert(//);
tableobject.Insert(//);
...
sessionobj.Commit();
```

NOTE: the tableobj object is a CTable that is initialized by the sessionobj CSession object.

I should be seeing a sizeable performance increase but I am not.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why would transactions improve performance? The advantage of a transaction is that you can roll it back at any point prior to the commit if any statement fails, not that it's faster. If anything, I'd expect a transaction to be *slower* because the DB has to simultaneously know what the table looks like both before and after the commit while the transaction is open. It still writes to disk because the DB has to remember everything to recover from a possible system failure. Transactions expand atomicity, not performance.

Comment: Because they allow you to batch writes to the disk based database.  I have personally seen transactions improve performance by a factor of 50 but I was using C#/.NET in that application.  I don't know why it doesn't help in C++.  In my current application, I am batching about 480 database inserts per transaction as opposed to 1 per transaction before my changes.

Comment: IOW, I am trying to increase database insert performance in general and sought out transactions as a way to do that.  Is there any other way I can significantly increase the performance of a large number of consecutive DB inserts?

Comment: Oh, I was unable to edit my previous comment due to a stupid timeout, but I was using SQLite instead of SQL CE in the C# application mentioned above.

Comment: @Bacon Bits was right about it being slower.  SQLite works in a fundamentally different way than SQL CE which is why I was seeing different behavior.